# Create link URL like wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

my site Link `www.myweb.com/detail.php`. I want to ask, how to change my link like same a wordpress link like `www.myweb.com/2016/05/05/title`

Currently, configuration htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(detail\.php)
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But it's not working, how to solve this.

Comment: you are using wordpress ?

Comment: Just a database default wp(integrated wp_post table),, to front site, I use a only php